# Solution for making Swagger documentation for C# project with classes constructed without POJO logic

Tags: c#, swagger

I have 2 classes:

- CardInfo, which contains properties and some static methods;
- Authorization, which contains 3 properties and several public methods to compose strings and boolean value.

Could you push me ahead in constructing controller class and generally the project which would use CardInfo and Authorization classes as sources for representation their structure of properties and methods in Swagger documentation, whether using SwashBuckle or NSwag components?
What kind of interfaces could I use in returning value from methods in controller class? Could you give me a set of them? I know that standard WeatherForecast solution for ASP.Net Web API with Swagger documentation uses IEnumerable<>. And I've found in some sources that  IActionResult is also used.
When said POJO logic I mean those model classes which don't contain complex functionality in terms of Java Spring and Java Persistence API.

I expect to get Swagger documentation which shows structure of classes under localhost in Visual Studio 2019 and .Net 5.

Comment: _"POJO"_ - this isn't a Java question!

Comment: POCO - Plain Old CLR Object - is the C# version of POJO... Swagger will show the structure of objects in the signature of Controller methods.... This question is a better fit for the softwarengineering stackexchange site I think. This site is for answering specific programming questions, not discussion of overall structure.

Comment: Thank you for quick answers! I will wait for additional answers till tomorrow and if the question will be stayed without new answers then I will post my question under https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.